# Getting JSON data of JSTree, and it's metadata

Tags: jquery, json, metadata, jstree, stringification

We're using jstree for a navigation menu editor, and have been assigning metadata to the nodes of the tree like this:

```
var data = currentNode.data("jstree");
data.title = textBoxTitle.val();
data.linkType = textBoxLink.val();
```

I can see that the `data` object contains the relevant properties, but not too sure where jquery keeps the associated data after this point.

When we come to save the data (serializing it to our server-side language), the metadata seems to be ignored...

```
var json = jQuery.jstree._reference(tree).get_json();
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
```

The `json` object is inspected to have no property describing the metadata.

**How do we serialize the object along with its metadata?**

Thanks in advance,

- Greg.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading the documentation briefly, it looks to me as if you should be using attributes on the nodes to store your metadata. You could use HTML5 "data-" attributes:

```
currentNode.attr('data-title', textBoxTitle.val());
currentNode.attr('data-link-type', textBoxLink.val());
```

then when you do the `.get_json()` from the tree you tell it what attributes you want:

```
var json = jQuery.jstree._reference(tree).get_json(-1, ['data-title', 'data-link-type', 'id', 'class']);
```

The `.get_json` function actually takes **2** lists of attribute names, one for `<li>` nodes and one for `<a>` nodes (in that order).  I don't know what your tree looks like so I'm not sure where your attributes would go. (Also that leading "-1" argument tells it to get the whole tree, which you were doing previously by just passing nothing.)

Answer (score 2):

you might use this namespace as well

```
$('#treeid').data().jstree 
$('#treeid').data().jstree.get_json()
```

and also there are other methods where you can get the data you need